# Creating InvocableMethod for OpportunityContactRole

Tags: apex, opportunity, opportunitycontactrole

I have seen lots of people struggle to insert opportunity contact roles as they cannot be inserted using process builder (not a first class object). There are some work around using flows but these do not work on professional edition and are time consuming to make.

My code should take variables from Process builder and then search for an existing opportunity contact role, if it does not exist insert one. It's quite simple but I cannot get it to compile/save! Grrr.

The errors are:
Variable does not exist: ContactId
Variable does not exist: OpportunityId
Variable does not exist: IsPrimary
Variable does not exist: Role
DML requires SObject or SObject list type: OpportunityContactRole

I have tried rewriting it different ways with no luck!

```
global class OpportunityContactRoleNew {

global class ActionRequest {
    @InvocableVariable(required=true)
    global ID ContactId;
    @InvocableVariable(required=true)
    global Id OpportunityId;
    @InvocableVariable(required=true)
    global boolean IsPrimary;
    @InvocableVariable(required=true)
    global string Role;
}

@InvocableMethod(label='Insert Opportunity Contact Role' description='Add an opportunity contact role from process builder')
global static void invokeService(List<ActionRequest> request){  

            //Look for existing opporunity contact role
            Id ContactID = [SELECT Id, ContactId FROM OpportunityContactRole WHERE ContactId = :request[0].ContactId].Id;

            //if doesn't exist try and add it 
            If(ContactID == null ){
                try{
                   OpportunityContactRole OCR =  new OpportunityContactRole();
                   OCR.ContactId = request[0].ContactId;
                   OCR.OpportunityId =request[0].OpportunityId;
                   OCR.IsPrimary =request[0].IsPrimary;
                   OCR.Role =request[0].Role;
                   insert OCR; 
                }catch(exception e){}
            }        



}






}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a little too late however just putting the answer as a reference to anybody who would face this.

This solution works means literally, OpportunityContactRole custom class is generated as an apex class in your organization hence system is getting confused about which OpportunityContactRole class to go to unless you specifically use System.OpportunityContactRole.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. I don't understand the solution so anyone who does let me know:

Added "Schema" before  OpportunityContactRole

```
  Schema.OpportunityContactRole OCR = new Schema.OpportunityContactRole(ContactId = request[0].ContactId,OpportunityId =request[0].OpportunityId,     IsPrimary =request[0].IsPrimary,    Role =request[0].Role);
                   insert OCR;
```